# How to instantiate a class in custom controller from within controller extension?

Tags: apex, controller, controller-extension

This should be simple. I have a custom controller like so

```
    public class MyClass {
    .
    .
    .
    public class MyType{
      String a;
      Integer b;
      List<Account> c;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

Now I am trying to instantiate MyType object from a controller extension, like so:

```
public class MyClassExtension {

    public MyClassExtension(MyClass controller) {
        // This is where I need help
        controller.MyType myTypeObj = new controller.MyType();
    }
```

How do I do this? A couple of syntaxes I tried resulted in errors. TIA.

Comment: I get Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: controller.MyType at line 4 column 42. Something is definitely up... the code is too long and complex to paste here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To instantiate a subclass you would need to prefix the parent class name, not its variable reference. Try this.

`MyClass.MyType myTypeObj = new MyClass.MyType();`

Comment: Good catch. I initially missed that. Sometimes the easiest solution is the right one!

Comment: You guys are awesome. Actually, more than that. Thanks a ton!

Comment: It possible to miss the obvious fact, however simple/basic that seems, at times :)